# Run into "Internal error occurred while performing container health check" when deploying with Gcloud

Tags: web-deployment, gcloud

So I'm very new with gcloud (cloud in general). Please assume me as a very beginner. So I know how to create image, but I have a problem with deploying. It kept running forever with this message:

```
X  Deploying... Internal error occurred while performing container health check.
  -  Creating Revision... Revision deployment finished. Waiting for health check to begin.
  .  Routing traffic...
  OK Setting IAM Policy...
Aborted by user.
```

In the Vscode, my app using the django framework run on the local server works perfectly fine. One thing I notice that because I kept running into the error when deploying, I tried many time to delete the current project and create a new project and create new image with the new project; therefore, I have a lot of images in https://gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker. I notice this because it said "something" already existed every time I deployed. But I don't know how to delete them because:

> You need permissions for this action.
> Required permission(s): storage.objects.delete

I don't know what happen here. I need help this for my bootcamp project. Also, please explain with basic tech terms because I'm really new to this. Thanks alot!

Comment: Which service did you deploy to? What commands did you use? What is the configuration? Edit your question will details.

Comment: I use “gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/devops-portfolio-project:v1” to create image
And “gcloud run deploy portfolio-project --port 8000 --region $REGION \
  --image gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/portfolio-project:v1 \
  --allow-unauthenticated” to deploy

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what service or configuration I used. All I did was creating a new project, uploaded a zip file contained my project folder with all the ymal file, dockerfile, ect. Unzipped, change the directory to the project folder. Created the image and deployed.

Comment: When you run your Django project locally, does browsing|`curl`'ing `localhost:8080` work correctly? Cloud Run expects the deployed service to listed on, the port provided by `--port=8080` (in this case, it's also the default).

Comment: My localhost is 8000 and it runs fine. I tried the console deployment and set the host to 8000 but still not work.  Keep showing "Internal error occurred while performing container health check."